# How to take a list of list from file to change into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have a file I wanna run through in a loop. My file looks something like this:

```
Hello Hello
A B C D
A B C D
B C D A
B C D A
C D A B
B C D A

Hello Bye
A C D B
C D A B
A C D B
D C A B
```

and I run a loop only through Bye, to blank line.

It should return:

```
 {(A, C, D, B): 2, (C, D, A, b):1, (D, C, A, B):1}
```

And is there a way i can call 'all' which would add all the permutations?

I want to do this without using any import.

So far my function looks like this:

```
# input_word = Hello or Bye
def file_to_dict (file, input_word):
    new_dict = {}
    new_list = []

    flag = False
    for line in f:
        if 'Hello' in line:
            continue
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        lElts = tuple(line.split(' '))
        if lElts in dRet:
            dRet[lElts] += 1
        else:
            dRet[lElts] = 1
    return dRet
```

Is there an alternative for continue?

And now this gives me an error saying:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: So what's wrong with it then? Give expected vs actual output

Comment: It gives me error.. i cant seem to take whats in the file with this:(

Comment: what's the error? Copy paste is your friend. Please include as much detail as possible when asking questions. Also, please format your code! in Python Formatting matters!

Comment: Do you mean `IndentationError`?

Comment: This error is raised whenever you try to work with a closed file. Make sure that file is a properly opened file. Just like this: `file = open('file_name','r')`

Comment: You have to define `dRet`, so just before `for line in f:`, add the line `dRet = {}`, also remove the space at the beginning of `for line in f:`

Answer (score 1):

```
read = False    
counting_dict = {}
#run through the lines in the file
for line in file:
    if read and 'Hello' not in line:
        #do as if the entry already exists
        try:
            counting_dict[tuple(line.split())] += 1
        #if not, create it
        except KeyError:
            counting_dict[tuple(line.split())] = 1
    elif 'Bye' in line:
        read = True
    #if 'Hello' is in the line but 'Bye' is not,set read to False
    else:
        read = False
```

Comment: I dont mind if the method is long, but it should be simpler to understand, if you can just edit my logic that would be great too

Comment: Can i ask what try does?? is it a separate built in function or just something to define another?

Comment: `try` allows to handle exceptions: if you simply do `a_dict[a_key] += 1` and `a_key` does not exist in the the dictionary, the error `KeyError` will be raised. In the above case, the program does not stop in this case, but the part under `except KeyError:` is executed, where the not existing key is added to the dictionary.

Comment: Can i ask what i was doing wrong?? If i have a new list then i am using it to make a dict.. Wont that work?

Answer (score 1):

something like this, split at `hello Bye`, and then use `dict.get()` to add values to the dictionary.

```
In [17]: with open("data.txt") as f:

    spl=f.read().split("Hello Bye")

    #now spl[1] is  

    #
    #A C D B
    #C D A B
    #A C D B
    #D C A B

    #we need to now split these at '\n', or may be use `splitlines()`
    #for every line apply split, which returns ['D', 'C', 'A', 'B']
    #apply tuple() to it, to make it hashable.
    #now you can use use either defaultdict(int) or dict.get() as used below.

    dic={}                         
    for x in spl[1].split('\n'):
        if x.strip():
            key=tuple(x.split())
            dic[key]=dic.get(key,0)+1;
    print dic
   ....:     
{('D', 'C', 'A', 'B'): 1, ('A', 'C', 'D', 'B'): 2, ('C', 'D', 'A', 'B'): 1}
```

Comment: Can you be more detailed.. and tell me what each thing is doing because i wanna use the idea of a code, not copy past a code :S

Comment: @user1853961 i've added some more details.

Comment: thanks alot! i am gonna try this..except this is a little advanced for my level

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of logic errors... I suggest you look up how `elif` works

```
def f_to_dict(f):
    dRet = {}
    for line in f:
        if 'Hello' in line:
            continue
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        lElts = tuple(line.split(' '))
        if lElts in dRet:
            dRet[lElts] += 1
        else:
            dRet[lElts] = 1
    return dRet
```

Comment: gives me this error:
for line in file:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: open the file first, then it should work. If you have a file with the name this_is_a_file.txt, type `file = open('this_is_a_file.txt','r')`.